# Split string in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to split a string being received from a props. 
For example: 
`this.props.searchedBook=Cinderella` (a fairy tale).

I am displaying that data like:

```
<span>You currently don't have data for <p>{this.props.searchedBook}</p></span>
```

I want to display only `Cindrella`. How do I do that?

Comment: You can use ```split``` function to do that. For example: ```{this.props.searchedBook.split(' ')[0]}```

Comment: Nothing to do with React, this is just a pure JS question. And it depends on how you want to split _in general_ -- do you want to show only the first word, or do you want to omit parts that are in ( ) ?

Comment: What makes you think that no-one's gonna search for "Peter Pan (a fairy tale)"? Note that there is a space between `Peter` and `Pan`. I suggest you come up with a more general approach to what you're trying to accomplish.

EDIT: Also, there's a book called "The Mysterious Disappearance of Leon (I Mean Noel)" - note the parenthesis in the title.

Answer (score 1):

If the name is always coming first in `this.props.searchedBook`, then you can use this

```
  this.props.searchedBook.split(' ')[0]
```